# Use a custom block inside another custom block

Tags: block-editor

How can I use a custom block inside another custom block?

I have created a custom block(Block A) that works fine.

Now I am creating another custom block(Block B) and want to embed the Block A inside it.

I tried to use the InnerBlocks like this

```
<InnerBlocks
    defaultBlock={[
         "Block A"
    ]}
    directInsert
/>
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Finally,I have found a solution. I can pass my custom block to the InnerBlocks inside a template prop.

```
    const TEMPLATE = [
        [
            "core/columns",
            {},
            [
                [
                    "core/column",
                    {},
                    [["custom/Block A", { url: "this is a url" }]],
                ],
                [
                    "core/column",
                    {},
                    [["core/paragraph", { placeholder: "Enter side content..." }]],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];


    <InnerBlocks template={TEMPLATE} />
```